# Query for earliest datetime and corresponding number field

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm attempting to update a table with a dollar amount based on the earliest datetime field from another table. For example:

```
Table 1
ID|INITIAL_ANNUAL_RATE_AMT|
1 | NULL (I want to update this to 25.02)

Table 2
ID|ANNUAL_RATE_AMT|STARTING_DATE|
1 |25.01          |1/1/2014
1 |25.02          |1/1/2013
```

I've got a query like this that retreives the earliest date from table 2 and the corresponding objects ID:

```
select ID,
         MIN(t2.STARTING_DATE) as EARLIEST_START_DATE
  from t2
  group by t2.ID
```

But how can I leverage this into an update statement that sets the `INITIAL_ANNUAL_RATE_AMT` in table 1 to the earliest corresponding value in table 2?

Something like this (which currently fails):

```
update t1
set t1.Initial_Annual_Rate__c = t3.ANNUAL_RATE_AMT
from t1, t2
left join
 (select t2.ID
         MIN(t2.STARTING_DATE) as EARLIEST_START_DATE
  from t2
  group by t2.DEAL_ID)
     as t3 ON (t3.DEAL_ID = t1.DEAL_ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use a CTE

```
;WITH C AS(
SELECT t.ID, EARLIEST_START_DATE, ANNUAL_RATE_AMT FROM(
select ID,
         MIN(t2.STARTING_DATE) as EARLIEST_START_DATE
  from @Table2 AS t2
  group by t2.ID) t
  INNER JOIN @Table2 AS t2 ON t2.ID = t.ID AND t.EARLIEST_START_DATE = t2.STARTING_DATE
)
UPDATE t1
SET INITIAL_ANNUAL_RATE_AMT = C.ANNUAL_RATE_AMT
FROM @Table1 AS t1
INNER JOIN C ON C.ID = t1.ID
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d3133/2)

Answer (score 0):

Another method, using a window function to get the first row in each ID partitioned set:

```
-- Setup test data
declare @table1 table (ID int, INITIAL_ANNUAL_RATE_AMT decimal(9,2))
declare @table2 table (ID int, ANNUAL_RATE_AMT  decimal(9,2), STARTING_DATE date)

INSERT INTO @table1 (ID, INITIAL_ANNUAL_RATE_AMT)
SELECT 1, NULL

INSERT INTO @table2 (ID, ANNUAL_RATE_AMT, STARTING_DATE)
SELECT 1,25.01,'1/1/2014'
UNION SELECT 1,25.02,'1/1/2013'

-- Do the update
;with table2WithIDRowNumbers as (
  select ID, ANNUAL_RATE_AMT, STARTING_DATE, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY STARTING_DATE) as rowNumber
  FROM @table2
)
UPDATE t1
SET INITIAL_ANNUAL_RATE_AMT=t2.ANNUAL_RATE_AMT
FROM table2WithIDRowNumbers t2
INNER JOIN @table1 t1 ON t1.ID=t2.ID
where t2.rowNumber=1

-- Show the result
SELECT * from @table1
```